# how to limit the contents in CJuiAutoComplete

Tags: yii

Hai I am working on CJuiAutoComplete in yii. Well I have to limit the the contents or result in the autocomplete. How can I do this. Please help?

Comment: how does your code look like now? edit: as in can you show what you have tried till now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your are fetching the autocomplete results from your DB then you should put the limit in your db request.
If it's from an array then you should slice your array to have only x values.

The `CJUIAutoComplete` is just displaying what you give him as options to autocomplete, it's up to you to deliver more or less options!

For now we don't know how you populate your `CJuiAutoComplete` so we can't help you more!

Comment: Thanks. I got it right. I was fetching the results from a database. Now I got it right.Thank you so much for your help....